# CATextLayer is ignoring NSMutableParagraphStyle

Tags: catextlayer

I want to use `NSMutableAttributedString` to draw the text on the `CATextLayer` with the text. I try set attributes to the like font and fontcolor of the `NSMutableAttributedString` through the `[attrString setAttributes:attributes range:range];` but all attributes in the `NSMutableParagraphStyle` are ignored.

```
let str = "I want to use NSMutableAttributedString to draw the text on the CATextLayer with the text. I try set attributes to the like font and fontcolor of the NSMutableAttributedString through the [attrString setAttributes:attributes range:range]; but all attributes in the NSMutableParagraphStyle are ignored."
    let att = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str)
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 12
    att.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, str.characters.count))
let contentLayer = initTextLayer("", andFontSize: 11)
    contentLayer.string = att
    contentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 30 * AUTOSIZESCALEX, y: CGRectGetMaxY(titleLayer.frame) + 15 * AUTOSIZESCALEY, width: SCREEN_WIDTH - 60 * AUTOSIZESCALEX, height: 200 * AUTOSIZESCALEY)
    self.contentView.layer.addSublayer(contentLayer)

func initTextLayer(title: String, andFontSize size: CGFloat) -> CATextLayer{
    let textLayer = CATextLayer()
    textLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "333333").CGColor
    textLayer.string = title
    textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentLeft
    textLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
    textLayer.shouldRasterize = false
    textLayer.wrapped = true
    textLayer.fontSize = size  * AUTOSIZESCALEY
    return textLayer
}
```

is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and used this:

```
    // Set text alignment. Apparently CATextLayer doesn't use value in NSAttributedString.
    if let style = text.attribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, atIndex: 0, effectiveRange: nil) as? NSParagraphStyle {
        switch style.alignment {
        case .Center:
            textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
        case .Left:
            textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentLeft
        case .Right:
            textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentRight
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer is still valid in 2019 and iOS 13…